Continuity of a function of CDFs in the sup norm
I'm interested in the properties of the function $G:\mathcal{F}\to\mathbb{R}_{\ge0}$ where $\mathcal{F}$ is a set of CDFs of real-valued random variables and $G$ is given by
$$G(F)=\int_\mathbb{R}F(x)(1-F(x))dx.$$
Specifically, I am interested in whether $G$ is continuous in the sup norm on $\mathcal{F}$. It seems clear this must be true if, say, $\mathcal{F}$ includes only CDFs of distributions that share a finite support, or that share a support that can be written as an interval $[a,b]$.
Is $G$ continuous in the sup norm on $\mathcal{F}$ if $\mathcal{F}$ is the set of all CDFs of distributions of real-valued random variables? If not, is there a broad class of CDFs $\mathcal{F}$ on which $G$ is continuous in the sup norm?


Is $G$ continuous in $\mathcal{F}$ with the sup norm if $\mathcal{F}$ is the set of all CDFs of distributions of real-valued random variables?

No, since $G$ is not even well defined for all CDFs. For a counterexample, consider the CDF $F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow [0,1]$ defined by
$$
F(x) = \begin{cases} 
    \displaystyle -\frac{1}{x}, & x < -1 \\ 
    \hfill 1, & 1 \leq x,
\end{cases}
$$
and observe that
$$\begin{array}{rcl}
\displaystyle\int F(x)(1-F(x))\, dx &\geq&\displaystyle  \int_{-\infty}^{-1} -\frac{1}{x}\left(\frac{x+1}{x}\right)\,dx \\ 
&=&\displaystyle \int_1^\infty \frac{u-1}{u^2}\,du\\ 
&=&\infty.
\end{array}$$

Is there a broad class of functions where $G$ is continuous?

This question is too broad. However, I can think of at least one reasonably broad class of functions where $G$ would indeed be continuous.
Uniform convergence implies pointwise convergence, so one would be tempted to use the Dominated Convergence Theorem to prove that $G$ is continuous. This would, in general, fail unless the sequence is dominated by an integrable control function $H$. In virtue of the latter, you can define the following class of functions:
$$ \mathcal{D}_H = \{F:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow[0,1]\mid F\text{ is a CDF and }F(1-F)\leq H\},\quad H\in L^1(\mathbb{R}). $$
For all $H\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$, the function $G:\mathcal{D}_H\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is continuous since it is sequentially continuous, that is, if $\{F_n\}\subset \mathcal{D}_H$, $F\in\mathcal{D}_H$, and $F_n\rightarrow F$ uniformly, then by the Dominated Convergence Theorem:
$$ \begin{array}{rl}
\displaystyle\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} G(F_n) &=\displaystyle \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \int F_n(1-F_n) \,dx \\ 
&=\displaystyle \int \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} F_n(1-F_n) \,dx \\ 
&=\displaystyle \int F(1-F) \,dx \\ 
&=\displaystyle G(F).
\end{array}
$$
Extra comments:

There are more general versions of the Dominated Convergence Theorem that might help you build larger classes of functions.
You can prove that $\mathcal{D}_H$ is closed, so you can compute limits inside it with no problems.
The class $\{F\mid F\text{ is a CDF and } \int F(1-F)\,dx<\infty\}$ is not closed. In fact, you can find a sequence $F_n$ in such a class such that $F_n\rightarrow F$ uniformly, where $F$ is defined as in the counterexample above.


Does $L^1(\mathbb{R})$ denote the class of integrable functions?

Yes, it does. You can read more about this space in Wikipedia: $L^p$ spaces.
